# AttachmentBuilder is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, constructor, discord.js

Lastest version of canvas, discord.js and node.js.

Here is the code:

```
    const attachment = new AttachmentBuilder(canvas.toBuffer("image/png"), {
      name: "DNI.png",
    });

    await interaction.reply({ files: [attachment] })

  },
```

The console/terminal says: "AttachmentBuilder is not a constructor" when I use the / command.

Comment: Show us your `import` declarations.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your forgot to import AttachmentBuilder frmom discord.js.

```
const { AttachmentBuilder} = require("discord.js");

//...

    const attachment = new AttachmentBuilder(canvas.toBuffer("image/png"), {
      name: "DNI.png",
    });

    await interaction.reply({ files: [attachment] })

  },
```

Answer (score 0):

Your attachment may already be an array, so there is no need to array it like embed.

So your code should be

`await interaction.reply({ files: attachment })`

not

`await interaction.reply({ files: [attachment] })`